# How to create a directory at connected http location through java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a folder structure at connected http location.I am getting the connection but I am not getting idea to creating directory.I tried by using file object but it is creating folder in my local.Can anyone help me in this?
is there any way to create directory at connceted url?

Comment: please follow the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You probably want to be using FTP to do this kind of thing.  HTTP doesn't have anything built into it to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. What you can do if you have access to the remote system, then you can write a ServiceEndpoint and a WebController for it.

Answer (score 0):

The point is: you are connected via the **[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)** protocol.

There is simply **no notion** at all regarding "file system" access on the remote system within that protocol.

If you want to use a HTTP request to manipulate the file system of your remote system, then **you** have to write code that processes that HTTP request on your *server* and does something *there*.

Or, in case we are talking about a specific server (not yours); then you have to **check** the specific API that this server offers and see if that includes a service to do what you think you have to do.